# Add a column to SYS_REFCURSOR in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sys-refcursor

I have a procedure MY_PROC that returns SYS_REFCURSOR. My new requirement is to create new procedure that returns SYS_REFCURSOR with all data returned by MY_RPOC plus one extra column with new data. I would like to reuse the procedure MY_PROC.

Is there any way in Oracle to add a column to SYS_REFCURSOR? Or do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please post your existing code?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3910022/266304)?

Comment: You can't modify a cursor once it has been opened. You can write a pile of code to work around this in various ways, but the code you write to avoid having to duplicate the cursor SQL will be longer and more difficult to understand and maintain than the "almost duplicated" code. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may open the cursor dynamically something like this:

```
OPEN cur
  FOR
   ' SELECT a,b,c' ||
   case when i_add_column = 'Y' then ',d'  end ||
   ' FROM table1'
```

The i_add_column is passed as parameter and based on the value the new column is added or not.