# Stored Procedure to return specific rows plsql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

Say I have a table as:

```
 create table product
(
  prod_code number(3),
  prod_name varchar2(20),
  prod_dept varchar2(20)
);
```

I want to write a procedure which takes in two parameters:

```
param_1 = col_name
param_2 = col_value
```

The procedure needs to check if the column exists and if it does then returns the row(s) with the values equal to `param_2`.

Example:

Say the procedure name is `getproddetails` and the parameters passed are like this:

execute `getproddetails('prod_id', 40)`

When I pass these two values then it should return the entire row with `prod_id=40`.

I can check weather the column exists or not but how to return the entire row(s) based on the values?

Any help would be great. I have written the following code but it doesn't work:

```
create or replace procedure getproductdetails(p_colname varchar2, p_value number)
is
  v_column_exists number :=0;
  cursor c1 is select * from product where p_colname = p_value;
  myrow c1%rowtype;
    BEGIN
    select count(*) into v_column_exists
    from user_tab_cols
    where column_name = p_colname and table_name = 'PRODUCT';

   if(v_column_exists > 0) then
     open c1;
      loop
        fetch c1 into myrow;
        exit when c1%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(myrow.prod_name || ' ' || myrow.prod_cost);
      end loop;
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('Column Not Found');
    end if;
   end getproductdetails;
```

Note that I am displaying only 2 columns but there are like 8 to 9 columns.

Comment: Why are you needing to do this? Is it for homework or something? This seems like an odd requirement for real world applications (although odd != impossible!)

Comment: Not exactly HW but just trying to learn. How to work with the values which can be number or varchar. If it cannot be done using both datatypes then atleast how to do it with number datatype as in the param_2 is a Number.

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to try and have a procedure that generalises the code - it makes things complicated, as now you have to deal with data conversion (what if the value is a number or a date?) as you have realised. Instead, it's far better to know what your application wants and code for specifics - e.g. have a procedure that returns the entire row for a given emp_id, and have a procedure that returns the rows when passed in the emp_name, etc. What you're after is do-able, but you have to ask yourself if it really makes sense to do it like that.

Comment: See [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/) on why generalisation is not necessarily a good thing, especially when taken to the extreme!

Comment: I do understand why it's a bad idea but just to know it can be done or not. What really is the requirement is passing the column name and the value which is going to definitive either a varchar or a number. So, how can I do it with a number? Like example 1 in the above question

Comment: You'd have to check for whether the column is a number or not via user_tab_columns

Comment: OK yeah I checked that. Its done. The main problem is how to check for the particular value as in the param_2 value passed?

Comment: I have pasted my code here: https://pastebin.com/nWfQRGH1
But this does not give the desired result. 
The cursor :`cursor c1 is select * from product where p_colname = p_value;` does not work but I need to check this condition. How?

Comment: Unclear, please post code directly by editing your original post. Read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work if you set `param_2` as `VARCHAR2`; use implicit conversion.

Here is what I would do, using `REF_CURSOR`:

```
create or replace procedure getempdetails (
   pcol_name in varchar2
 , pcol_value in varchar2
 , pres_cursor out sys_refcursor
) is 
begin
  open pres_cursor for 'SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_dept FROM emp WHERE '
  ||pcol_name||'='''||pcol_value||'''';
end;
/
```

## Edit: more elegant with the use of `:pcol_name`;

but I could not find how to make it work with the implicit conversion.

```
create or replace procedure getempdetails (
   pcol_name in varchar2
 , pcol_value in varchar2
 , pres_cursor out sys_refcursor
) is 
begin
   OPEN pres_cursor 
    FOR 'SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_dept FROM emp WHERE :pcol_name='''||pcol_value||''''
  USING pcol_name;
end;
```

/

Then use the cursor that way:

```
SQL>  insert into emp values(1, 'John', 'IT');

1 row created.

SQL> variable r refcursor;
SQL> exec  getempdetails('emp_id', '1', :r);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>  print r
         1 John                 IT

SQL>
```

Search a little more if you want to use this cursor inside further PL/SQL. E.g. 
great examples like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230428/executing-a-dynamic-sql-statement-into-a-sys-refcursor) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910022/how-to-call-one-stored-proc-from-anther-and-modify-refcursor-that-is-returned?noredirect=1&lq=1).

NB: 
Basically, [in PL/SQL, `'` escapes `'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315340/pl-sql-how-to-escape-single-quote-in-a-string). So if you want a  `'` inside a string in PL/SQL, you write `' I want a quote there -> '' <- '`

Comment: You are calling the procedure with 3 parameters. Please check my code which I have posted in previous comments.

Comment: @KaranGupta, You have to edit your question to avoid such misunderstandings. I'll wait further notice.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine but please enlighten me about the "||" operator used. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks, `||` is concatenation operation.

Comment: Yeah I know it is concatenation but I don't understand how and why it is used here? The single quotes makes it more confusing.

Comment: The `||` and `''` are necessary to make the query dynamically dependent on your parameters. If you want to avoid this, then use the `:param` technique. I edited for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Yeah that's ok. Could you please tell me where I can read about this "dynamically dependent query". I will be able to get a better understanding then.

Comment: You should look examples of the use of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. You'll learn how to build queries that are only checked at execution time, so be careful with them, it require good exception handling.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot. I know where to look now.

Answer (score 0):

> how to return the entire row(s) based on the values?

You can create a out parameter and it can be of the type of the table, like:

`Procedure gettemplates(
columnname in varchar2, 
value in varchar2, 
entirerowreturn out yourtable%rowtype) is ...`

Comment: That wouldn't help if there were multiple rows to be returned. Instead, I'd go with a ref cursor.